# Qt keyboard input in other language

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt5

Well in word processors, when I change font to `Preeti`, typing "asdfgh" will result in displaying "बकमानज". I tried changing `QPlainTextEdit`'s font to  `Preeti`, but it's still typing "asdfgh"

How can achieve same in Qt?

Here's what I am doing:

```
@pyqtSlot()
def select_font(self):
    font, ok = QFontDialog.getFont(self)
    if ok:
        ## the text in ui.text_edit is in unicode
        self.ui.text_edit.setFont(font)
```

Obviously the font exists in the system. The displaying of font is also correct (when loaded from .txt file). What's not working is typing in that font. The key-mapping from keyboard to the chosen font is what i am talking about.

Help in c++ or python: language doesn't matter here.

Comment: Do other fonts work? Does Preeti work on other "standard" applications (like your basic text editor, be it Notepad, Gedit or whatever).

Comment: Perhaps your word processor doesn't correctly fall back to a Latin font when it can't find `a`..`s` in the Preeti font, but just chooses something from Preeti as substitute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that the font is not being recognized in your application. Check to see if you have installed the font. You can also try adding the `preeti.ttf` file to resources and adding it to the app using:

```
QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(“:/fonts/preeti.ttf”);
```

I found stylesheets to be more reliable (than using `setFont(QFont)`) for setting font. Use `textEdit->setStyleSheet(font-family: 'Preeti');`.

## EDIT

setting stylesheet from QFontDialog() can be done in following way in python

```
@pyqtSlot()
def select_font(self):
    font, ok = QFontDialog.getFont(self)
    if ok:
        params = font.toString().split(",") # The string is :"Preeti,9,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0"
        self.ui.text_edit.setStyleSheet("font-family :%s;font-size:%spt;" % (params[0], params[1]))
```

Comment: I have made edit to the question. The problem is not in the existence of font in system.

Comment: Just tested this out myself (with a `QLabel`). Setting a `QFont` for the widget did not work. Instead, my only option was to use `setStyleSheet("font-family: Preeti;")`. HTML tags did not work either.

Comment: Can you test it out in your system and let me know? I can change the answer if it works.

Comment: Things look quiet complicated here, Now the characters are displayed correctly. But saving the `TextEdit::plainText()` won't create the unicode mapping from the font. Is there a way to convert what I have typed into unicode?

Comment: I wouldn't expect you to get Unicode text as you are just changing font in normal alphanumeric characters. You will probably have to write a mapper function for that.